# Problem getting correct output of filter in VHDL simulation

Tags: fpga, filter, vhdl

I have simulated a FIR filter. VHDL editor gives me no errors and compiles the code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE work.types_numeric.ALL;            
entity fir_filter_numeric is
    GENERIC
        (
          bits_data:           natural := 12;                         
          taps:                natural := 69                          
        );
    ---------------------

--<<<< hier die Namen der Ports festlegen
    Port
        (
        MainClk:                                    in  STD_LOGIC;  
        Rst:                      in  std_logic;
    h :             in coefficient_array;  
        sample_input:             in std_logic_vector ( (bits_data - 1) downto 0);
        sample_output:            out signed( (bits_data - 1) downto 0);
        FIRin:                    in std_logic;
        sample_out:               out std_logic
        );
  end fir_filter_numeric;


--! @copydoc    productDescription
  architecture Behavioral of fir_filter_numeric is
        
    type data_array is array (integer range 0 to (taps - 1))  of signed ( ( bits_data-1 ) downto 0);
  type mult_array is array (integer range 0 to (taps - 1))  of signed ( ( 2*bits_data-1 ) downto 0);      
    signal shift_data    : data_array     := (others => (others => '0')); 
  signal mult_data     : mult_array     := (others => (others => '0')); 
  
  begin  
     main_process : process(MainClk)
     variable add_data: signed (24 downto 0);
        begin       
        -- synchronous_reset
        if rising_edge(MainClk)  then
          if Rst = '1' then                   -- do reset
          sample_out <=                                     '0';      
      else
               shift_data    <=  signed(sample_input)    & shift_data( 0 to ( taps - 2));
              if FirIn = '1' then
                  -- count = 0, data_in 
                  shift_data(0)    <=  signed(sample_input);
              else 
                  -- (M-1)-zeros, count = 1:3
                  shift_data(0)    <=  (others => '0');
              end if; 

               add_data := (others => '0'); 
               for i in 0 to taps-1 loop
                    add_data  := add_data    + mult_data(i); 
               end loop;            
               sample_output   <= add_data (22 downto 11);
                end if; 
            end if; --

          end process main_process;
   

product_calc : 
 for i in 0 to taps-1 generate
    mult_data(i)   <= (shift_data(i) * h(i)); 
  end generate;  
  
    end Behavioral;
```

The simulation gives me an output  and to check if the output is correct I am going to send `1` as input.  If I send `1` ( in signal processing it is Dirac impulse I believe), I will get filter coefficients in the output.

[image]

Unfortunately I have gotten the wrong output.

Could someone help me to find where I have mistaken?

Comment: Dirac is one sample, only. If you send only 1s then it's Heaviside and you get the step response.

Comment: Do the same simulation but track your internal signals, have fun with your aha-erlebnis.

Comment: @DonFusili what is aha-erlebnis?

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/aha-erlebnis

Comment: About here someone could ask what is the right result and how do you reproduce the wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are starting in VHDL.
Many points make that it will be difficult to synthesize and meet timings: There is a lack of pipeline in your code.

Still, here is a functional bug I see

This part is wrong:

```
shift_data    <=  signed(sample_input)    & shift_data( 0 to ( taps - 2));
if FirIn = '1' then
  -- count = 0, data_in 
  shift_data(0)    <=  signed(sample_input);
else 
  -- (M-1)-zeros, count = 1:3
  shift_data(0)    <=  (others => '0');
end if;
```

I would write it like this:

```
if FirIn = '1' then
    shift_data(0)           <=  signed(sample_input);
    shift_data(1 to taps-1) <=  shift_data(0 to taps-2);
end if;
```

After correcting the previous stuff, it is possible that you don't see anything at the output as you select bit 22 to 11 from add_data
`sample_output   <= add_data (22 downto 11);`

Comment: -1 Your change introduces rather than fixes a problem. From the waves it's clear that FirIn shows when *new* data arrives. Your FIR pipeline still needs to shift forward even when no new data is available. Also comments like "difficult to meet timing" don't mean anything here and just show rote parotting. I do 9 element additions on 200MHz all the time at the moment, 69 at 50MHz wouldn't be an issue in my current technology and we don't even *know* OPs targetted tech, or if they even want to go beyond simulation.

Comment: The FIR pipleline still needs to shift forward? Shift forward which samples? You look so brave...

Comment: ... zeroes. Extension towards the infinities of the sequence with zeroes is necessary. Your "solution" will simply ignore any coefficient that's a higher index than the applied input sequence length, which is not part of the definition of a FIR filter. There are adjustments that do this, but the implementation idea of OP is more often seen than whatever this is supposed to be. Being flippant about it does not make you less wrong, it just makes you flippantly wrong.

Comment: Just to make this completely clear: Not shifting it forward and extending the sequence means the impulse response is only the first coefficient. As OP correctly notes, it should be the full coefficient sequence.

Comment: It is a pitty, you are so wrong... still, I have no time to spend chatting on this